# How can I dynamically generate operator classes?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to generate dynamically operator classes.

The code below is based on the code at the end of this [link](https://pythonapi.upbge.fr/info_overview.html)

```
cls.CustomOp = []
for i in ['a', 'b']:
    idname = "object.operator_" + i

    def func(self, context):
        print("Hello World", self.bl_idname)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    opclass = type("DynOp" + i,
                   (bpy.types.Operator, ),
                   {"bl_idname": idname, "bl_label": "Test", "execute": func},
                   )
    bpy.utils.register_class(opclass)
    cls.CustomOp = cls.CustomOp + [opclass]
```

I have tried the code above in poll and draw contexts, but always the same :

> "RuntimeError: register_class(...): can't run in readonly state 'DynOpa'".

What does readonly context mean?
How to do it (and from where) in a non-readonly context?

Comment: The question for me is what is behind needing to dynamically generate operator classes?

Comment: @RayMairlot at the base this is related to solve this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/changing-tooltip-for-menu-entries-which-use-the-same-operator. But that can be a more general question

Comment: You can not run any commands that change properties whithin a poll or a draw function. As far as i know the only context where you can change something is when an operator actually runs or within a callback function that is started "on property change" when you for example set an option in a panel.

Comment: ok @GaiaClary, so this kind of approach cannot work in the context of your question ? or is it possible to apply this in another context (before a poll or a draw) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found, you can't register operators during some actions such as drawing or polling. We can define custom operators within an addons `register()` or within an operators `execute()` method, you can also manually run your script from blender's text editor without any issue.

For brevity I'll replace your for loop with a function called `create_custom_operator()`

```
def create_custom_operator(i):
    idname = "object.operator_" + i
    .... # rest as above
```

You can then use it in an addons `register()` -

```
def register():
    for n in ['a','b','c']:
        create_custom_operator(n)
```

Or you could use it in an operator's `execute()`. Note that I use a file list to define the operators here, we can do this in an operator's execute but not while registering an addon as we can't access the filesystem during addon registration.

```
class MakeCustomOperators(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Create custom operators"""
    bl_idname = 'object.add_custom_ops'
    bl_label = 'Add operators'
    bl_description ='Dynamically create multiple operators'

    def execute(self, context):
        for f in os.listdir('/path/to/data'):
            create_custom_operator(f)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I have given a more complete example in [answer to the question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56799/935) that inspired this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So for instance the list of custom operators could be defined either in the register part or in an execute function of a modal operator (in order to have this list dynamically updated), isn't it ?

Comment: Yes if you want to dynamically update the operators you will want to create an operator that will create them when run, it can read a file, list a directory or scan objects in the scene to define the list. This could be used for a refresh button in a panel or menu. If you keep a list of the operators you can remove the old ones before creating a new list so you don't get duplicates or stale operators.