# Code advice for blender

Tags: python

New to coding, Where to start, Where do I look to understand blender tool tips?
TO change blender tools tips is that a kernel thing or could a python script over ride tool tip?

Thanks

Comment: HI. Can you expand on what you mean by "understand" tooltips? What is it about the tooltips you don't understand? Also, if understanding tooltips and editing tooltips are two separate questions, then please ask them separately.

Comment: I've learned one thing here at stack exchange over the last few months. I'm clearly not skilled enough to even ask the right question's. I applaud your standards and would not want to muddy the waters. I withdraw my question and membership. I hope someday to meet BSE's standards and be able to contribute someday.

Comment: No one is asking you to remove your question or trying to suggest that you are no 'worthy' to ask. There is an [edit] link under your question which allows you to add more information. I'm sure you can expand on your details a bit.

Comment: Before you go, you may find [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/changing-tooltip-for-menu-entries-which-use-the-same-operator) of some use.

Comment: He wants to change tooltips in blender. And he wants to understand how they are stored. What exactly is hard to understand about this question?

Comment: @Haunt_House I was unsure if it was 2 separate questions: One on understanding tooltips (e.g. interpreting the python displayed in the tooltip) and one about changing the source code. That's why I asked for some clarification.

Comment: @OthoapProto Yes we can seem a bit strict on what questions we allow. But every new user have a lot to learn, blender BSE its no small task. However you deleting your account is not going to help. You've been here for 4 months (and quite frankly you are writing better posts then many new users.) and you've already been a help to some folks. Please don't leave. I'd rather have users that do "not want to muddy the waters" then the ones that just spam out bad questions. (which you are not one).