# pass a string variable from UI Layout to display properly in Operator bl_description

Tags: python

In the UI Panel layout I have:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row()
    props = row.operator("myops.addthings", text="HEAD")

    #text variable here
    props.sometext ="my object name"
```

In the operator I have:

```
sometext = bpy.props.StringProperty()
bl_description = "Add "+str(sometext)
```

The tool tip however doesn't seem to be displaying the "sometext" as regular string, see the screen captured as below:

[image]

Seems the string returns as "", what is the fix to get it displayed?

Comment: As far as I know this is a limitation and an operator cannot have procedural description. You have to have multiple operators for multiple tool_tips..

Comment: Need to unregister and reregister class to change the tooltip. [Somewhat related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/changing-tooltip-for-menu-entries-which-use-the-same-operator)

Comment: I was hoping to make an operator that works with different buttons to add different mesh by retrieving the variables in the layout correspondingly ... so this cannot be done? I have to make an operator for each?