# Create an adaptive description for an Operator that take an attribute?

Tags: python

Sometimes the attributes of an operator can change quite dratically the output for the end user.

is there a way to make the description of this operator adaptive to the attribute ?

exemple in the script below:

```
class SCATTER_OT_print(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname      = "scatter.print"
    bl_label       = ""

    pref : bpy.props.StringProperty()
    bl_description = "print: " + pref #Adaptive desctiption ? 

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.pref)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the operator will change it's functionality in such a way that the original description will no longer be informative?

Comment: Albeit the dupe listed is attempting to change label rather than description, the same answer applies.  Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56727/changing-tooltip-for-menu-entries-which-use-the-same-operator