# Convert Strings to objects with attributes to get their values

Tags: python

After days of searching I have to ask now:

How can I get attributes out of a string list?

What I want is :

```
thing = bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao
print(thing)
```

"thing" has now stored True.

But I have a string list. How can I get these strings to tell me their attributes?

```
Andi = [
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_bloom",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_ssr",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_motion_blur",
]
```

I was going to try **getattr**, but there it needs an object first, not strings.

The reason I do this is so that I can save and recall render settings.
First I worked with the preset system integrated in blender as explained here:

[Python add drop down menu that stores data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/python-add-drop-down-menu-that-stores-data)

But unfortunately the render settings change with each Blender version, which brings a lot of problems. That's why I'm looking for a way to have full control over everything myself, so that the render settings can be tested via Try Except statement and not just generate an error right away.

Comment: 99% sure it's [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - tell us what you need it for, exactly.

Comment: All clear. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not a skilled programmer, but an artist first and foremost. I have edited the question. Hopefully it is better this way.

Comment: So to summarize, you want to be able to save "presets" of your eevee render settings, and be able to change it at runtime using some kind of list in the interface ? Have you explored simply using different scenes with different settings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Andi` list stores a list of Python statements (assignments) in the form of strings. **If you trust this list to not contain malevolent code** (it could tell your computer to download a trojan virus, for example) you can tell Python to `exec`ute it:

```py
import bpy

Andi = [
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao = False",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_bloom = False",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_ssr = True",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_motion_blur = True",
]

for s in Andi:
    exec(s)
```

You can also parse the strings in order to obtain the information that interests you, e.g.

```py
import bpy

Andi = [
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao = False",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_bloom = False",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_ssr = True",
        "bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_motion_blur = True",
]

d = {s.split("=")[0].split(".")[-1]:(s[-4:]=="True") for s in Andi}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'use_gtao ': False, 'use_bloom ': False, 'use_ssr ': True, 'use_motion_blur ': True}
```

To get all possible values (**security risk due to eval!**):

```py
d = {s.split("=")[0].split(".")[-1]:eval(s.split("=")[1]) for s in Andi}
```

To get only values (**security risk due to eval!**):

```py
values = [eval(s.split("=")[1]) for s in Andi]
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thank you! If it's not too much trouble, how can I just find the attribute? So only True or False?  
(I'm a little confused about attributes and values. "True" is the attribute, right?)

Comment: `True` and `False` are Boolean **values**. `d = {s.split("=")[0].split(".")[-1]:(s[-4:]=="True") for s in Andi}` is a dictionary comprehension, resulting in a dictionary of an attribute e.g. `use_gtao` leading to a value e.g. `False`. To only get values: `values = [s[-4:]=="True" for s in Andi]`